# C Wrong Answer when squaring

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm learning C using C by Example. There is a question where we need to take an input integer and square it and print it to the screen. I'm having a strange error, when no matter what Int I enter it give me this output:

```
Please enter a number.
5
Number = 2686764         Square of Number = 2686760
```

Here is the program I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>   //for getch()


main(){

    int number, square;

    printf("Please enter a number. \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    square = number*number;
    printf("\n Number = %d ", &number);
    printf("\t Square of Number = %d", &square);
    getch();


}
```

Comment: Enable all warnings when compiling and the compiler messages will speak for themselves then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the above answers ... look at this example:

```
int number = 5;

printf(" %d\n", number);     // Prints value of 'number'.
printf(" %p\n", &number);    // Prints address of 'number'.
printf(" %d\n", *(&number)); // Prints value at address of 'number' ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You are printing the memory address of the `number` and `square` variables, not their values.

Try this instead:

```
printf("\n Number = %d ", number);
printf("\t Square of Number = %d", square);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `printf` statements are incorrect. Do not use `&` in this case:

```
printf("\n Number = %d ", number);
printf("\t Square of Number = %d", square);
```